# html code embeded within javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a picture in my container `div` using `container.innerHTML`, but all I got is the picture's URL.

My code:

```
<html>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- The picture's URL -->
        <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/Z1kpfgtHmpWHS/200.gif">
    </div>
    <script>
    var container = document.querySelector(".container");

    //I intend to display the image within javascript instead of using img tag in HTML
    container.innerHTML = "https://media3.giphy.com/media/Z1kpfgtHmpWHS/200.gif";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My questions are:

1. I am wondering since I can display that image using  tag in HTML, but can I embedded HTML code within the javascript? All I have is the image URL.
2. the `container.innerHTML = URL` is not working, so how is the correct solution should be like?

Comment: Use an `img` tag and set the `src` rather then setting the `innetHTML` of a div as a string?

Answer (score 0):

### If the image already exists:

You could give the image an id and select it using `document.getElementById('image-id')` and then set it with the `src` attribute, i.e:

```
document.getElementById('imageId').src = url;
```

### If you want to programmatically create the image:

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = url;
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add html element instead of url in InnerHTML

```
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.innerHTML ='<img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/Z1kpfgtHmpWHS/200.gif">';
```

or you could use

```
 var containerImg = document.querySelector(".container img");
 containerImg.src= 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/Z1kpfgtHmpWHS/200.gif';
```